# Systemd service or alternative in docker

Tags: docker, systemd

I am running a WireGuard service with a user interface and want to deploy WireGuard with docker-compose while leaving user interface external. Looking for alternatives or the correct way to execute '**wg-restart.service**'.

1. **/etc/systemd/system/wg-restart.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart WireGuard
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0.service
```

2. **/etc/systemd/system/wg.watch**

```
[Unit]
Description=Watch for file wg0.conf changes 

[Path]
PathModified=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can bind volume from docker container and watch for file "**wg0.conf**" changes, but not sure how to restart WireGuard service which is running in docker. After reading documentation found 4 restart policies.

```
restart: "no"
restart: always
restart: on-failure
restart: unless-stopped
```

Manual way can be used with unless-stopped policy. So I have trigger **when to restart**, but don`t **how to restart**, unless if **wg-restart.service** runs script to stop, remove, deploy?

Comment: Run the two processes in separate containers, and delete and recreate one or the other if its configuration changes.  Do not attempt to run systemd inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker run command, the switch —restart=(RESTART_MODE) can be useful and for docker-compose you have useful options to use.
See:

- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/